# Powershell - Run SCP command using CYGWIN but also expand variables

Tags: powershell, cygwin, scp

I need to expand variables before running the `SCP` command as a result I can't use single quote. If I run the script using double quotes in  `Powershell ISE` it works fine.

But doesn't work if I run the script through command prompt.

I'm using zabbix to run the script which calls the script as `[cmd /C "powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .\myscript.ps1"]`

Here is the code that needs to run SCP using Cygwin bash.

```
if ((test-path  "$zipFile"))

{ 

C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -l "set -x; scp /cygdrive/e/logs/$foldername/dir1/$foldername.zip root@10.10.10.10:~/"

}
```

Output:

```
/usr/bin/bash: set -x;  /cygdrive/e/logs/myfolder/dir1/server.zip root@10.10.10.10:~/: No such file or directory
```

If I run the same command above in Cygwin manually it works.

I even tried to use `bash -l -c` but then the SSH session is stuck maybe because the `root@10.10.10.10` becomes $1 according to the documentation.

[Documentation link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)

```
   -c        If the -c option is present, then commands are read from

             the first non-option argument command_string.  If there are

             arguments after the command_string, the first argument is

             assigned to $0 and any remaining arguments are assigned to

             the positional parameters.  The assignment to $0 sets the

             name of the shell, which is used in warning and error

             messages.
```

Comment: Try constructing the string? e.g. `'set -x; scp /cygdrive/e/logs/' + $foldername + '/dir1/' + $foldername + '.zip root@10.10.10.10:~/'` or similar. Could also put that in brackets....

Comment: Same error. No such file or directory. I looks /cygdrive/ isn't mounted when calling the ps script. I tried 'set -x; ls /cygdrive/c/' and it showed the same error.

Comment: hm `set -x; /usr/bin/echo "test"` says no such file or directory too

Comment: oh i have to use the `bash -l -c` switch and then ls and echo works. But `-c switch` doesn't work with scp. The session still hangs when constructing the string as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. It was halting when using `bash -c` was due to `StrictHostKeyChecking`, the known hosts thing (where you get a prompt to type yes/no).  I set the `-v` switch to `SCP` and it showed me the Debug logs where it was halting.

Had to set `scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null` options.

The complete line now looks like the following:

```
c:\$cygwin_folder\bin\bash.exe -c ("/usr/bin/scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -v -i /cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa  /cygdrive/e/logs/$foldername/dir1/$foldername.zip root@10.10.10.10:~/")
```